# Is there an adjective for "double standard"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

"[double standard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20standard)" is a *noun-phrase* that means

> a set of principles that applies differently and usually more rigorously to one group of people or circumstances than to another ...

I see an alternate definition, *bimetallism*, but that applies to economics, so I don't think *bimetallic* is appropriate.

Is there an adjective that means double standard?

Comment: Unfair comes to mind, but that is not precisely the same meaning. I don't believe there is an adjectival form of the word "double-standard."  To use it as an adjective, you would need to reword your sentence to use double standard as a noun.

Comment: You should provide a sentence. Even if there isn't a normal word, you can use a phrase to the same effect: *it was an unequally and differently applied rule*.

Comment: Or *unjustly and  inconsistently applied rule*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks, I was hoping there was an equivalent single word so I could be less verbose.  Additionally I'd like to avoid a direct accusation, but rather more softly describe something.  For example: avoid - _You all have a double standard when it comes to doing xyz._ for something like _The [???] views are a major impediment for progress_ or even better _The [???] behavior_ ...

Answer (score 1):

A common adjective implying application of double standards is ***discriminatory***.

ODO:

> **[discriminatory](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discriminatory)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
> Making or showing an unfair or prejudicial distinction between different categories of people or things, especially on the
> grounds of race, age, or sex.
>
> ‘discriminatory employment practices’
>
> ‘It is discriminatory as the closure will disproportionately affect older people and those with disabilities.’